Insert JSON into Postgres via NiFi
I'm trying insert record with JSON into Postgres table with column type of jsonb using AVROSchemaRegistry and Processor "PutDatabaseRecord".
Apache NiFi version:  nifi-2.0.0-M2-RC4
Postgres version: 12.12
Processor "PutDatabaseRecord" properties:

My AVRO schema:
{
    "name": "ebs_data",
    "namespace": "nifi",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
              {
               ***
              },
              {
            "name": "log", 
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "log_rec",
                    "fields": [
                        {"name": "log_level", "type": ["string","null"]},
                        {"name": "log_message", "type": ["string","null"]},
                        {"name": "log_date", "type": ["string","null"]}
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

And I get this stacktrace:
2024-07-29 12:50:29,388 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Scheduled PutDatabaseRecord[id=1f964dda-cd85-3499-190a-a3724f133e23
] to run with 1 threads
2024-07-29 12:50:29,392 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig HikariCPConnectionPool[id=28d9771d-2472-3215-407c-038ac82c0116] - maxLife
time is less than 30000ms, setting to default 1800000ms.
2024-07-29 12:50:29,393 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource HikariCPConnectionPool[id=28d9771d-2472-3215-407c-038ac82c0116] - Sta
rting...
2024-07-29 12:50:29,528 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool HikariCPConnectionPool[id=28d9771d-2472-3215-407c-038ac82c0116] - Adde
d connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@3c556a44
2024-07-29 12:50:29,530 INFO [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource HikariCPConnectionPool[id=28d9771d-2472-3215-407c-038ac82c0116] - Sta
rt completed.
2024-07-29 12:50:29,701 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.standard.PutDatabaseRecord PutDatabaseRecord[id=1f964dda-cd85-3499-190a-a3724f133e23] Failed to
 put Records to database for StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=acbcce68-f9f4-45b3-b88d-7e8694167097,claim=StandardContentClaim [resourceClaim=StandardResourceClaim[id=1722
246429765-23, container=default, section=23], offset=9744, length=73727],offset=0,name=349045823834552,size=73727]. Routing to failure.
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO ebs_data.ebs_data.rnd_heap_and_parts (***, log) VALUES (***,('[Ljava.lang.Object;@1d1458e1')) was aborted: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "Ljava" is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: [Ljava...  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.BatchResultHandler.handleError(BatchResultHandler.java:165)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2413)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:579)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.internalExecuteBatch(PgStatement.java:912)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:936)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1733)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.executeBatch(ProxyStatement.java:127)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:254)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler$ProxiedReturnObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:240)
        at jdk.proxy23/jdk.proxy23.$Proxy206.executeBatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.executeDML(PutDatabaseRecord.java:958)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.putToDatabase(PutDatabaseRecord.java:1140)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutDatabaseRecord.onTrigger(PutDatabaseRecord.java:559)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1274)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:244)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:102)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type json
  Detail: Token "Ljava" is invalid.
  Where: JSON data, line 1: [Ljava...
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2725)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
        ... 25 common frames omitted
2024-07-29 12:50:29,811 INFO [Flow Service Tasks Thread-1] o.a.nifi.controller.StandardFlowService Saved flow controller org.apache.nifi.controller.FlowController@3230417f // Another save pending = false

What I'm doing wrong?
Expecting successfully inserted record.
